# Flashing GTX560 BIOS to GTX970

Tags: bios, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

Recently, I sold a no brand GTX970 and the buyer wrote back claiming it was a flashed GTX560. I'm rather skeptical about this for the following reasons:

1. The card is tested to work
2. These cards are many architectures apart, making incompatibility likely
3. GPU-Z shows GTX970 specs

Thus, is this possible at all? (Assuming the supplier has quite advanced GPU knowledge)

Comment: 4 series apart? Very doubtful...

Comment: Sounds like he's trying to scam you for a refund.

Comment: It should be noted, re: #1 that it works isn't conclusive and re: #2 no, not really, and those fake cards do work in Windows thanks to Nvidia's unified driver architecture (no so in Linux where the either the drivers don't install or they do but you get a black screen in the next reboot and re: #3 GPU-Z results are meaningless (fake cards do report as the spoofed chip, not as the real one), unless there are significant differences when compared to the reference card, other than the name that will always be the spoofed one.

Comment: @Attie [Case of GTX 550 Ti sold as GTX 1050 Ti](https://www.wykop.pl/link/4132069/test-karty-z-chin-gtx-1050-ti-za-250-zlotych/). Video is in Polish, but you can see at 4:20 that it reports as GTX 1050 Ti in GPU-Z (note the memory size: 4608 MB). At 5:50 you can see a bare chip of GTX 550 Ti. I suspect it actually has a 550 BIOS modified to identify as 1050. There are serious side effects though, games mis-detect this GPU and try to use features that aren't available in 550.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlikely, if you know the card and bought it from a "good" source and have performed a benchmark to validate the performance of the card.

Wikipedia has a good [List of Nvidia graphics processing units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units)

The GTX560:

- processor: GF114
- shaders: 336
- GFLOPS: 1088

The GTX970:

- processor: GM204-200
- shaders: 1664
- GFLOPS: 3494

Performance is going to be wildly different between the cards.

It is slightly possible that someone edited the BIOS of a 560 to report it as a 970 and it could still work, but this could be easily determined by running a benchmark on the card and checking the performance against one of the online databases such as [UserBenchmark](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com) or [VideoCardBenchmark](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net)

If you are certain that you bought the card from a reputable supplier and know the provenance of the card and that it's performance matches what you expect then it could be a scam from your buyer.

If you bought the card from a dodgy site and it was a fraction of the cost of any other place selling "similar" cards then it could be that you got scammed by that site and have (unwittingly) ended up scamming someone else.

Your only *real* option is to have the person return the card to you, making 100% certain that what you get back is what you sent out, and then testing the card appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I found a Elitegroup GTX560 that looks quite similar to the GTX970, which probably explains his suspicion. What do you think are the odds of the card being something else and masquerading as a GTX970? I just want to be really sure

Comment: I would have said it is reasonably slim, due to there being a massive conspicuous performance gap, but get them to run something like UserBenchmark or Passmark (linked in my updated answer) as that would give some performance figures on the card that could tell you either way. If he still says it is the 560 then take care with returns as he may send you something which is not what you sent out.

Comment: Personal experience: Yes, it's plausible. GTX560 (or GTX540) are used in this kind of scams. I'm not sure it's possible to make one of those report as a GTX970 but as a GTX750ti it certainly is. Besides running the suggested benchmarks which aren't necessarily conclusive, ask them to show you photographic proof of the real chip under the heatsink. That's definitive.

Comment: Just the tip of the iceberg: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/862620/got-a-fake-gpu-need-help-identifying-it-/?offset=5

Comment: @MichaelBay this is why I have trust issues >:-|

Comment: @Mokubai I didn't have trust issues (and would've dismissed such claims right away) until I was scammed with a fake Nvidia years ago. Then I investigated and found out this sort of spoofing was actually common at eBay and Aliexpress. Lesson learned, always be skeptical.

Comment: After I heard about the prevalence of fake USB and SD cards on eBay I've always been sceptical about buying anything along those lines. I've seen a few people on this site trying to fake the graphics card displayed in a laptop and this actually concerns me. What happened to just being a decent human being and not trying to rip each other off? If this question is anything to go by these scams flow both ways, with buyers ripping off sellers by reporting them as fakes when they aren't.